# Making RewriteRule portable/relative to the directory of the .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following RewriteRule which makes it so that someone going to `domain.com/somepage/?page=3` will be 301 redirected to `domain.com/somepage/3/`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?page=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /somepage/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

This is in a `.htaccess` file in the `somepage` directory.

Now, this *works* fine... but it's a bit of a hassle. I have about a dozen pages that are paginated, all in their own directory. I would like to just be able to copy the `.htaccess` file into each directory and not have to worry about editing each one. For example, I also want `domain.com/someotherpage/?page=3` to redirect to `domain.com/someotherpage/3/`, but to do this I'd have to edit the respective `.htaccess` file and change the `somepage` part to `someotherpage`.

It also causes problems when I copy my entire site to a different server. Normally, the site is placed in the root directory. However, when I'm running it locally, I place the entire site in a folder called `dev`. So now I have to go through all of the RewriteRules and change it from `/somepage/%1/` to `/dev/somepage/%1`. This, as you can probably imagine, is incredibly tedious.

So, is there a way of changing this so that the path that it redirects to is relative to the `.htaccess` file, rather than from the server's root, so that I can reuse the same `.htaccess` multiple times without changing it, and so that I can also move my entire site into a `dev` directory without needing to change anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get rewrite base dynamically captured using a separate rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=BASE:%2]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?page=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

**Explanation:**

- You can use `$0` captured from `RewriteRule` in your `RewriteCond` because `mod_rewrite` actually **processes a ruleset backwards**. It starts with the pattern in the `RewriteRule`, and if it matches, goes on to check the one or more `RewriteCond`.
- So as you can see in a `RewriteCond`, the LHS (test string) can use backreference variables e.g. `$1`, `$2` OR `%1`, `%2` etc but RHS side i.e. condition string **cannot use** these `$1`, `$2` OR `%1`, `%2` variables.
- Inside the RHS condition part only backreference we can use are **internal back-references** i.e. the groups we have captured in this condition itself. They are denoted by `\1`, `\2` etc.
- In your `RewriteCond` first captured group is `([^#]*)`. It will be represented by internal back-reference `\1.
- As you can mark out that this rule is basically finding `RewriteBase` dynamically by comparing `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `$0`. An example of `%{REQUEST_URI}` will be `/directory/foobar.php` and example of `$0` for same example URI will be `foobar.php`. `^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$` is putting the difference in 2nd captured group `%2` or `\2`. Here it will populate `%2` or `\2` with the value `/directory/` which is used later in setting up env variable `%{ENV:BASE}` i.e. `E=BASE:%2`.

Comment: Thanks, it works great! Do you mind explaining a bit about what's actually going on here? I hate just copying code without actually understanding it.

Comment: Added a detailed explanation of above answer.

Comment: Crazy stuff, thanks! No wonder you've authored a regex-book ;)